# numpy error when saving png with pyplot polar projection

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

This code (simplified version of http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
plt.savefig("fig.png")
```

Causes the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 4, in <module>
    plt.savefig("fig.png")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1422, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 505, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 56, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1035, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 56, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2088, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 56, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1097, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 56, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 235, in draw
    self.gridline.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 56, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 551, in draw
    tpath, affine = transf_path.get_transformed_path_and_affine()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2562, in get_transformed_path_and_affine
    self._revalidate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2539, in _revalidate
    self._transform.transform_path_non_affine(self._path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2230, in transform_path_non_affine
    self._a.transform_path(path))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2227, in transform_path_non_affine
    return self._a.transform_path_non_affine(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2230, in transform_path_non_affine
    self._a.transform_path(path))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/projections/polar.py", line 72, in transform_path_non_affine
    ipath = path.interpolated(path._interpolation_steps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 553, in interpolated
    vertices = simple_linear_interpolation(self.vertices, steps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1712, in simple_linear_interpolation
    result = np.zeros(new_shape, a.dtype)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The reason of the crash is using `projection='polar'`, since without this projection it works fine.

I can't try to display the result because I am working on a remote webserver without X Display.
Using:

- python 3.4.3
- 14.04.5 LTS
- matplotib 1.3.1

The exact same setup except for matplotlib version (1.5.1) works in a different machine. I can also make it work in python2.7.

I tried upgrading matplotlib to version higher than 1.3, but couldn't find it in apt-get repositories, and `sudo pip3 install matplotlib==x.x.x` failed, as well as building from source.

Any ideas why this crashes?

Comment: Does is also crash when plotting actual data? Does it crash in other cases, where you don't use polar axes?

Comment: I updated my question with the info you ask for

Comment: Unless you find someone with the exact same configuration, such an error is hard to come by. I would guess that something is incompatible (like numpy version too high for mpl 1.3 or so) or something got destroyed in an attempt to update. I usually have those problems when trying to update a package which requires numpy and which then tries to update numpy although the requirement is already fulfilled. Is it an option to uninstall python completely and install all the newest versions from scratch?

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. re-installing python is not an option for me. Since I found out this didn't crash under Python 2, I will run it like this for the moment